# Unable to Establish Internet Connection from Docker Container to the Internet

Tags: linux, docker, networking, dns, containers

So I tried using phpmailer to send Mails from a contact form inside of a docker contaiener.
It did not work, tried using busybox container and `ping google.com`. -> `bad adress`
There was no connection possible with the default bridge network or with custom ones.
But it worked with my host network.

What I already tried:

- changing the host dns to `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4` -> checked if docker dns changes aswell (it did)
- `net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1`
- disabling the firewall

My Environement:

- nginx as reverse proxy (not dockerized)
- docker with my containers and disabled ip-tables
- ufw blocking all ports but ssh, https, http, outgoing is ALLOWED